# How to keep repeating and multiple staggering css and JS animations smooth. Tried using gsap and css but nothing helping performance-wise

Tags: javascript, css, performance, animation, gsap

I want to get the best performance i can on animations for my landing page of my project and here I am getting sluggiest, 
I am trying GSAP and raw css and i think none are helping performance gets too laggy at times,

-> I have seen many websites using hardcore and way more complex with animations going sweetly silk continuously and supporting all platforms including mobile phones mostly as well, but my animations are chirpy even when running at PC,

I have been trying to get the solutions, have tried to

1. remove all the other animating properties other than transform or opacity and
2. have added css 3d transform hack ,
3. not using animations on elements that affect the layout to repaint,
4. Using Gsap as well none are helping,

and now i am out of ideas how to get it working, if anyone wants to see my site, this is the link :

[webkrushers.com/test/template](http://webkrushers.com/test/template)

Note:

the preloader animation lags sometimes and the home screen animation as well, if we get through this i have one more place where animations are not going so well. Hope to get it all sorted and that someone else also learns something from the solutions.
you can see it, its in development not so responsive, so open it up at 80% zoom on full HD screens and 67% on HD screens. I would really like help from anyone who can assist me along the way, if he/she feels so. I would also like some recommendations on bettering my UI if someone sees some improvement or replacement that can be made.

if nothing can be done, should i move to canvas or webGl if so, can anyone shed some light on from where i should begin? 
I have known canvas and have learned just a lil bit of the fundamentals but have to learn a lot for doing these things i suppose but I dont know nothing about web GL so please explain and refer sources.

Comment: Have you looked into `will-change` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change)?

Comment: ya i have used will-change on my preloader animation on every transform i am making

Comment: You can see the real lagging when you Open the Developer tools and limit the network speed to maybe 1 or 2 Mbits/sec or anything that lets you see the loader for a few seconds.